# How to show an image on my app from firebase storage?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I can't let the app show the profile image picture on my android app, I can succesfully upload it but the code to show it in the app doesn't work.
The problem is my app that can't convert the firebase link in an image and i don't really know why ,the code is exactly the same from a youtube tutorial.

[image: Realtime database user children]
[image: Profile image in the Storage]

ProfileActivity.java

```
package com.example.scrapbase11;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageView;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private CircleImageView Profileimage;
    private TextView usernickname, userfirstlastname, usercomment, registrationdate;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference UsersRef;
    private StorageReference UserProfileImageRef;
    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;
    private String currentuserid;
    final static int Gallery_Pick = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentuserid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        UserProfileImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile Images");
        usernickname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_nickname);
        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentuserid);
        userfirstlastname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_firstlastname);
        usercomment = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_comment);
        Profileimage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_profile_pic);
        registrationdate= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.terzarow);

        UsersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
             if (snapshot.exists()){

                 String myusernickname = snapshot.child("nickname").getValue().toString();
                 String myusercomment = snapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
                 String myfamilyname = snapshot.child("familyname").getValue().toString();
                 String mygivenname = snapshot.child("givenname").getValue().toString();
                 String myregistrationdate = snapshot.child("registrationdate").getValue().toString();

                 usernickname.setText("@" + myusernickname);
                 usercomment.setText(myusercomment);
                 userfirstlastname.setText(mygivenname + " " + myfamilyname);
                 registrationdate.setText(myregistrationdate);
             }
             else {
                 Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Errore del database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });

        Profileimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, Gallery_Pick);
            }
        });



        UsersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
            {
                if(snapshot.exists())
                {
                    if (snapshot.hasChild("profileimage"))
                    {
                        String image = snapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();
                        Picasso.get().load(image).into(Profileimage);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Please select profile image first.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==Gallery_Pick && resultCode==RESULT_OK && data!=null)
        {
            Uri ImageUri = data.getData();
            CropImage.activity()
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(this);

        }
        if(requestCode==CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                loadingBar.setTitle("Profile image updating");
                loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait...");
                loadingBar.show();
                loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

                StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImageRef.child(currentuserid + ".jpg");
                filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()){

                                final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                                UsersRef.child("profileimage").setValue(currentuserid + ".jpg")
                                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                                    Intent setupIntent = new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, ProfileActivity.class);
                                                    startActivity(setupIntent);
                                                    Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Profile Image stored succesfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                    String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                                                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                                                    Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Error Occured", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error occured: Image can't be cropped. Try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loadingBar.dismiss();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This is the main part of the code which include the part to show the image:

```
 if(snapshot.exists())
                {
                    if (snapshot.hasChild("profileimage"))
                    {
                        String image = snapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();
                        Picasso.get().load(image).into(Profileimage);
                    }
```

EDIT: I've also tried to put                              UsersRef.child("profileimage").setValue(downloadUrl)
But the result is the same just the code for the profileimage is different in the database, this is the result[image: realtime db]

Comment: Have you tried to check what happens if the task is not successful?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
UsersRef.child("profileimage").setValue(currentuserid + ".jpg")
```

with

```
UsersRef.child("profileimage").setValue(downloadUrl)
```

EDIT-:

also call `addOnSuccessListener` first not `addOnCompleteListener`

```
.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        String image = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString());
    }
});
```

Inside `onSuccess` call `addOnCompleteListener`

Comment: Hi Krishan sorry if I didn't tell you. I've already tried that method, Unfortunately the result is the same. I update my post right now

Comment: Have a look at the last photo that I've put, it gives me "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@382793f"

Comment: check the edited answer. you don't get url from `final String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();`

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is not to get the String like you do but you need an asyn task and handle the success method like in my function for example

```
    /**
 * Function that send the new photo to our Firebase Storage
 */
private void updatePhoto() {

    runOnUiThread(() -> {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        final byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
        final UploadTask uploadTask = mStorage.child("Users_Profiles").child(userName).putBytes(data);
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(e -> {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Photo upload failed, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }).addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
            if (taskSnapshot.getMetadata() != null) {
                if (taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference() != null) {
                    Task<Uri> result = taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
                    result.addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {
                        imageURL = uri.toString();
                        ref.child("Users").child(userName).child("pic_url").setValue(imageURL);
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });

}
```

As you can see, I'm converting the photo first to an byte[] data and then use and uploadTask to upload the file.
after doing that I'm using the OnSuccessListner to make sure my file actually uploaded to the firestore, then I'm using the Task result to get the file URL

```
taskSnapshot.getStorage().getDownloadUrl();
```

then when you have that link, you can use it like you want with your code

```
  Picasso.get().load(image).into(imageURL);
```

the imageURL is just so you could understand that this is the string I'm using to load an image to the ImageView using Picasso.

You can use my function or modify it if it helps you in anyway.

Comment: Thank you Yakir, I just do not understand what imageBitmap is supposed to be. Is it my equivalent of Profileimage in the CircleImageView?

Comment: the imageBitmap is just the image that I store in the imageView and then compress it ( I got a function that I wrote to reduce file size, let me know if you want that too ).
After that I use it in the data byte object to store it in the firestore and then download it after the process is done.

If that answer helped you, give it a vote up :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple method for you and it worked with me :

after setup the firebase and firebase-storage in your app...

**First :**

the xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**second :**

the MainActivity :

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    FirebaseStorage firebaseStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

    StorageReference storageReference = firebaseStorage.getReference();

    storageReference.child("images/main.jpg").getBytes(Long.MAX_VALUE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle any errors
        }
    });

}

}
```